# How to change link on click, to match an ID that I get from another API request

Tags: javascript, api, hyperlink

I might've expressed myself badly in the title, so here it is:
I want to change the link address of the IMDB button, in a way that it will add the tvshow ID to the URL, so it will look something like this (https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2861424).

I have 2 separate requests to the API (themoviedb API), one is to show details for the tv show (where some brainiac didn't include the imdb_id), and another request from the same API provider to get external_ids (and that way to get that imdb_id). But I can't connect the imdb_id from the second request, to put it on the IMDB button, so it will add the `imdb_id` to the URL and open the corresponding page.

Separately, it works, I can get the `imdb_id` on the second request, but I will have to output it beneath all the structure that I already have, and it ruins it whole.

```
function getShowInfo(){
    let showId = sessionStorage.getItem("showId");

    axios.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/"+showId+'?api_key=fa155f635119344d33fcb84fb807649b&language=en-US')
        .then((response)=>{
            let series = response.data;
            let output = `
                <div class="moviePage">
                    <div class="poster"><img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/${series.poster_path}"></div>
                    <div class="info">
                        <h2>${series.name}</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li><strong>Genres:</strong> ${series.genres[0].name}</li>
                            <li><strong>Episode runtime:</strong> ${series.episode_run_time[0]}min </li>
                            <li><strong>Frist air date:</strong> ${series.first_air_date}</li>
                            <li><strong>Networks:</strong> ${series.networks[0].name}</li>
                            <li><strong>Popularity:</strong> ${series.popularity} %</li>
                            <li><strong>Number of episodes:</strong> ${series.number_of_episodes}</li>
                            <li><strong>Number of seasons:</strong> ${series.number_of_seasons}</li>
                            <li><strong>Production companies:</strong> ${series.production_companies[0].name},${series.production_companies[1].name}</li>
                            <li><strong>Status:</strong> ${series.status}</li>
                            <li><strong>Type: </strong>${series.type}</li>
                        </ul>

                        <div class="buttons"> ERROR
                            <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/???"target="_blank"> IMDB Link </a>
                            <a href="#" onclick="openTrailer()"> Trailer </a>
                            <a href="https://www.titlovi.com/titlovi/?prijevod=${series.name}" target="_blank"> Subtitle </a>
                            <a href="https://www.thepiratebay.org/search/${series.name}" target="_blank"> Pirate bay </a>
                            <a href="javascript:history.back()"> Go back </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="plot">
                    <h3>Plot: </h3>
                    <p>${series.overview}</p>
                </div>
            `;
            let info = document.getElementById("movie");
            info.innerHTML = output;
        })
        .catch ((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
        });
        axios.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/"+showId+'/external_ids?api_key=fa155f635119344d33fcb84fb807649b&language=en-US')
            .then((response)=>{
                console.log(response)
                let imdb = response.data.imdb_id;
                console.log(imdb);
            })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Promise.all` to only create the HTML once both responses have come back, so that you can use the `imdb_id` *and* the series information at once:

```
function getShowInfo() {
  const showId = sessionStorage.getItem("showId");

  const seriesProm = axios.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/" + showId + '?api_key=fa155f635119344d33fcb84fb807649b&language=en-US');
  const imdbProm = axios.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/" + showId + '/external_ids?api_key=fa155f635119344d33fcb84fb807649b&language=en-US');
  Promse.all([seriesProm, imdbProm])
    .then(([seriesResp, imdbResp]) => {
      const series = seriesResp.data;
      const imdb_id = imdbResp.data.imdb_id;
      let output = `
        <div class="moviePage">
        <div class="poster"><img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/${series.poster_path}"></div>
        ...
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/${imdb_id}" target="_blank"> IMDB Link </a>
        ...
```

Comment: You're the best ! Thanks a lot, this works perfectly as it is supposed to. Quick question, I can "append" more requests doing this (by defining them as variable first, then using the Promise.all)? or is it limited? Once again, thanks a lot !

Comment: You can add as many promises as you want, there's no limit except your network connection.

Comment: Great. Thanks for looking into my problem, really helped me a lot and taught me something new. Cheers !